# State Almost Duplicated Between Views

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, architecture, state

I have several views interacting with very similar state (slightly different subsets of a master). First instinct was to reuse a master, resetting it between views.

This approach does everything I need it to, but doesn't *seem* elegant. Disregarding details of how to actually do it, one would think of the state as owned by each view separately. I've made it global only because it made more sense to just go with the standard Redux approach than to spend a whole lot of time solving a problem that wasn't  really a problem.

Duplicating a whole lot of reducers and action creators or inventing some heavy name-space abstraction would be even worse, but if the views end up diverging more over time, using the same master would  become less efficient than it currently is. Not too worried about that actually happening, but I imagine it has bearing on the standard solution that I assume exists.

Am I missing a really sleek way of mostly-reusing these with little code duplication or complexity, or some other common solution? It seems unlikely that this really is the best way to handle it.

Comment: But if it's not used anywhere else why make it global? Also, If the data structure is the same or similar maybe create a class for it, and instantiate different objects for each component?

Comment: You're probably right that it shouldn't be global. The reason it currently is is that I wanted to stick as closely as possible to the Redux tutorials, all of them having a single global store. Redux as a whole has been great, but is it possible to create separate stores for each view? Maybe I misunderstand the way you are thinking of to make it non-global.

Comment: Ideally, what I would want is to reuse all the action creators, reducers, and middleware between views, but with two differences from the current setup: each view's state would be separate, and each "copy" would only have the necessary ~80% of the master set. Not sure how to do that, or if it's really the best goal anyway.